# I got a small problem

Tags: functions

Let $f(X) = 5X + 4$, $g(X) = 4X + 3$. Suppose that $f \circ g (X) = aX + b$. Find $a + b$. How can I find sum of $a$ and $b$

Comment: Have you tried computing $f\circ g$? $f\circ g(x) = f(g(x))=f(4x+3)=5(4x+3)+4$..

Comment: yes, i got 20X + 19 = aX+ b but i stuck right heree

Comment: That means $a=20,b=19$... you did the hard part already.

Comment: oh god, that's so simple. Why can i not think about it, stupid me

Comment: Well,.... there *is* the subtlety as to why that is an answer or the only answer...  You can get $(20-a)X = 19-b$ and this *must* be true for all $X$s.  So it it must be true for $X=0$.  And it must be true for $X = 1$.  So $(20-a)\cdot 0 = 19-b$.  There is only one answer for $b$.  And  $(20-a)\cdot 1 = 19-b$. For that one answer for $b$ there is only one answer for $a$.  ... But that's probably more details then you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f\circ g(x) = f(g(x))$.

$f(whatever) = 5(whatever) + 4$ so $f(g(x)) = 5(g(x)) + 4$.

And $g(x) = 4x + 3$.  So

$f(g(x)) = 5(g(x)) + 4 = 5(4x + 3) + 4$.

We are told $f\circ g(x) = ax + b$.

So $f\circ g(x) = 5(4x+3) + 4 = ax + b$.

So what is $a$ and $b$?

It's a straight forward question.